# Parsing Json in android Studio with Google map api

Tags: android, json, google-maps, fragment

I am very new to android development. I am trying to parse the "coordinates" as marker and "nameline" as title of the corresponding coordinates from the below JSON snippet:

```
[{
    "osm_id": "45737878",
    "jsongeoms": [{
        "longitude": 4.379361,
        "latitude": 45.4325822004212
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3798922,
        "latitude": 45.43297760042115
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3799371,
        "latitude": 45.43302460042115
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3800508,
        "latitude": 45.433070900421136
    }],
    "way": "0102000020E610000004000000ED82C1357784114005D281DA5EB746409F05FC7502851140CDDA5CCF6BB74640F9252C3B0E8511400E96A0596DB74640494673092C8511403B1405DE6EB74640",
    "highway": "residential",
    **"nameline"**: "Rue Vaucanson",
    "maxspeed": null
}, {
    "osm_id": "272992421",
    "jsongeoms": [{
        "longitude": 4.3803678,
        "latitude": 45.432611700421205
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.380298399999999,
        "latitude": 45.43271530042118
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3800861,
        "latitude": 45.43302760042115
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3800508,
        "latitude": 45.433070900421136
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3799992,
        "latitude": 45.43315010042112
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3796751,
        "latitude": 45.433588600421075
    }, {
        "longitude": 4.3796212,
        "latitude": 45.43364890042106
    }], "way": "0102000020E6100000070000004ECEF5227F8511408896F8D15FB746406EE29AF16C851140D6E4073763B7464020A8644A358511407F09CB726DB74640494673092C8511403B1405DE6EB746405006A2821E851140AFC8657671B74640106CA68CC98411400C5DCDD47FB746401D797B6BBB8411409EA0A2CE81B74640",
    "highway": "secondary",
    **"nameline"**: "Boulevard Martin Bernard",
    "maxspeed": null
},
...
]
```

But my output is not satisfactory.

Please see my code below and tell me where I went wrong:

```
JsonArrayRequest request= new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
      try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("jsongeoms");
        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
          JSONObject jsongeoms = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          double longitude = jsongeoms.getDouble("longitude");
          double latitude = jsongeoms.getDouble("latitude");
          LatLng sainte = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sainte).title("Service Result"));
          mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sainte));
          mMap.getMaxZoomLevel();
        }

        /* Enter code here */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have pasted here is not valid json.
what do you mean by "my output is not satisfactory"? what data would you like to get and what are you currently getting?

Comment: is it simply crashing due to ArrayIndexOutOfBound?
remember, .length() will tell you how many items are in an array but in java the first element starts counting from position 0 and you would want to loop until:

i < response.length()-1

Comment: The app is not crashing. I am not getting all the coordinates. from 1st array of "jsongeoms" I need all the coordinates but only 1 coordinates I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArrayRequest request= new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i= 0;i< response.length();i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String naming= jsonObject.getString("nameline");
                        String highway= jsonObject.getString("highway");
                        String speed = jsonObject.getString("maxspeed");
                        String way = jsonObject.getString("way");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("jsongeoms");
                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject jsongeoms = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            double longitude = jsongeoms.getDouble("longitude");
                            double latitude = jsongeoms.getDouble("latitude");
                            LatLng sainte = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sainte).title(naming)
                                    .snippet(highway.concat(speed).concat(way))
                                    .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp)));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sainte));
                            mMap.getMaxZoomLevel();


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            },
```